# VIM omnicppcomplete does not work for function parameters

Tags: c++, vim, omnicppcomplete

I'm trying to use omnicppcomplete in VIM and I can't get it to work for variables passed to a function. For example, typing the following

```
function1( MyObject obj ) {
    obj.|
}
```

results in "--Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found"

If I define a local variable within the function:

```
function1 ( MyClass obj) {
    MyClass obj2;
    obj2.|
}
```

it works fine and I get a popup list of the members. It also works well for global objects but does not seem to be able to determine what the variable is when it is passed as a function parameter.

My .vimrc contains:

```
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/cpp
set tags+=~/Projects/myproject/Software/tags

" OmniCppComplete
let OmniCpp_NamespaceSearch = 2
let OmniCpp_GlobalScopeSearch = 1
let OmniCpp_ShowAccess = 1
let OmniCpp_ShowPrototypeInAbbr = 1 " show function parameters
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteDot = 1 " autocomplete after .
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteArrow = 1 " autocomplete after ->
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteScope = 1 " autocomplete after ::
let OmniCpp_DefaultNamespaces = ["std", "_GLIBCXX_STD"]
let OmniCpp_LocalSearchDecl = 1 " use local search function, bracket on 1st column
let OmniCpp_DisplayMode = 1 
au BufNewFile,BufRead,BufEnter *.cpp,*.hpp set omnifunc=omni#cpp#complete#Main
au CursorMovedI,InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|silent! pclose|endif
set completeopt=menuone,menu,longest,preview


map <F8> :!/usr/bin/ctags -R --exclude=backups --language-force=C++ --sort=yes -c++-kinds=+pl --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -f ~/Software/tags ~/Software .<cr>
```

Comment: Works perfectly here, with your exact OmniCpp options. You use `MyObject` in one case and `MyClass` in the other, perhaps this is the error?

Comment: I don't see any settings in here to regenerate the tags in ~/Projects/myproject/Software/tags  Are those dated, by chance?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, omnicppcomplete relies on ctags which is not really efficient regarding C++ understanding.

You should have a look at clang_complete. It's likely to give better results.